# In mysql, varchar type is used to store Date type data, and extra points and 0 appear at the end

Tags: java, mysql, date, varchar

When I use JDBC to connect to MySQL, I store an element of type Date, but in the database, the type of this field is varchar. I checked the format of the data at the breakpoint. When I inserted it into the database, it was still of Date type, but it changed in the database. There was an extra point and 0 at the end. Now, the table structure will not change for a while. I don't know what else to do.

This is the data type in Java code, which is date type. The corresponding type in the database is varchar.

```
private Date offlineTime;
```

This is the code for setting the value.

```
setOfflineTime(DateUtils.StringToDate(request.getParameter("onofflineTime"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

This is a picture of the object's data in the code.

[image: picture of the object's data]

This is a picture of the data in the database

[image: picture of the data in the database]

Comment: the object's data in the code.         Thu Sep 03 00:00:00 CST 2020                                        
data in the database.                     2020-09-03 00:00:00.0

Comment: So what is the problem? Everything looks fine for me

Comment: That is **Millisecond in second** of your time and due to using Date, all section of your time are zero forever. Try to use `SimpleDateFormat` in Java, `Date` is deprecated!

Comment: Why don't you simply insert the value of `request.getParameter("onofflineTime")` into the DB?

Comment: The problem is that there was no point and 0 in the previous database. I want to remove this point and 0. @ClausBönnhoff

Comment: I've considered that SimpleDateFormat is thread unsafe, so I don't use it.@majidhajibaba

Comment: This is to consider the regularization of Dates.@ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: offlineTime is of type Date in the code, and the field corresponding to MySQL is of varchar type, while the type returned by the front end is of String type. Because there are too many codes in Java, it can't be cleaned up once, so there is no way to change this type.@ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: This point is part of the date time format in the database (depending on its version). So why do you want to remove it. It should be completely uninteresting for you how the date is stored in the data. Thats nothing you should care about

Comment: However, the type stored in my MySQL is varchar, which may cause me to make errors when comparing date types.@ClausBönnhoff